# Property of decreasing functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions

I was reading the proof of a theorem, and then I got stuck into this sentence:

"Since $f(k)=e^{-\frac{k^2}{m}}$ is a decreasing function, we have that:
$$\int_k^{k+1}e^{-\frac{x^2}{m}}d x\le e^{-\frac{k^2}{m}}\le\int_{k-1}^ke^{-\frac{x^2}{m}}dx"$$
I cannot understand how can I prove that this is true, and if it's true only in this case or for all decreasing functions and all integration intervals (in this case $k \in \mathbb{N}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an application of the fact that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then
$$
m(b-a)\leq \int_{a}^bf(x)\, dx\le M(b-a)
$$
where $M$ is the maximum and $m$ is the minimum of $f$ on $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 1):

This is just the fact that
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx\le(b-a)\max_{[a, b]}f(x)$$
and
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx\ge(b-a)\min_{[a, b]}f(x)$$
(assuming $f$ is continuous).